# how to support multiple third-party dll versions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, com

My .NET app referencing com object. My task is to be able to build my app without changing my code with different dll which is referenced on it.

How can i reference 2 versions of the same com reference? Is configuration manager can help here?

thanks

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223195/referencing-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly

Answer (score 1):

If the other version is backward compatible, you can just replace the existing reference with the new one.
If it's not backward compatible, you may need to change some of your code.
If you want to use some of the functions in the new version, you may also need to change some code.

Comment: This makes about as much sense as the question!

Comment: let me rephrase my question: i want to be able to build my app with BOTH versions, so in the end i'll get 2 versions of my app, each one referencing different dll. i want to acheive that without duplicating my project.

Comment: You should be able to add multiple versions of the same .dll to your project references, but how to distinguish between them at runtime is beyond me.  How do you know which version of the component you want to use?